# What is an alternative way to say "Note that" in academic writing?

Tags: american-english, writing, writing-style, academia

In my academic writing, when I want to connect the context and emphasize something, I almost always use a sentence structure like this:

> Note that...

An example in an academic paper is given below:
[image]

So my question is:

What is an alternative way to say, "Note that...," in academic writing in the above context? Thank you.

Comment: Google "nota bene".  Not exactly the sense you're using above, but in the same ballpark.  (And really hoity-toity, to impress the academics.)

Comment: It would be good to put quotes around "valid" in this case.

Comment: "... layout, where "valid" means [only] that ..." If something's really worth noting you should try to find a way to note it without telling your reader to do so, IMO.

Comment: One approach that writers frequently use is to call out the importance of the following remark. For example, "Crucially, however, 'valid' here means only that..." or "Significantly, however, 'valid' here means only that..." I can't confidently offer this as an answer, though,because I don't know whether academic writing generally approves of or condemns this technique.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's writing advice/POB

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best advice is: don't. 
Just leave it out. 
Readers do not like being constantly (or even repeatedly) reminded to pay attention.

If it is a fact, state it as a fact. If it is an opinion, clarify that it is an opinion. If it is somehow related to other statements, use connectors to clarify or emphasize that relationship, such as *however, moreover, nevertheless, alternatively, therefore, despite*.

Answer (score 8):

***It is to be observed*** that

*(/Please/One should/) **Observe that***

*(One should) **Bear in mind** that*

*(One should) **Keep in mind** that*

Answer (score 1):

It's a little more informal, but you can use "Remember that" or "Keep in mind". Alternatively, you could just leave the leader off and say "Valid here only...".